# Creating a product gallery with EF 6 and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a website for someone and am having a small issue. I'll admit I'm a little new to MVC and EF so I've got this issue. My Index view shows my products, but it shows them in a straight up and down list, like the table I created it supposed to do.

What I'm trying to do is create a gallery, where they're side by side for say 4 in a row, then move on to the next row and so forth (God I know this is making sense). Here's my view

```
@model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<br />
               <img src="@item.Image.ImagePath"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

And of course it's doing what it's supposed to do. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Consider using div elements with `float:left;` and `width: 25%`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I would like to thank you for all your help the past couple days. It means a lot when I can get help while learning the ins and outs of MVC

Comment: Pleasure. I assume you have worked it out, but [here is a simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vkc8myy/) showing what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has anything close to this issue this is what I came up with and it works just the way I was looking for:

```
@model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Products</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div style="float:left; width:25%">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)<br />
            <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="@item.Id" />
            <div>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
            <div><img src="@item.Image.ImagePath" /></div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" style="width:50px;" /></div>
            <div>@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id })</div>
        </div>
    }
```

I do, however have one question, in my controller how can I format the price as currency, I tried this:

```
IEnumerable<DisplayProductsViewModel> model = products.Select(p => new DisplayProductsViewModel()
{
    Id = p.ProductId,
    Name = p.ProductName,
    Image = p.ProductImage,
    Price = string.Format("{0:C}",p.ProductPrice)
}).ToList();
```

And get the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression

Comment: You should not be formatting the value in the query, but rather add the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]` to the property. The `@Html.DisplayFor()` helper will then render it correctly (delete the leading `$` in your view code)

Comment: Note also `<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="@item.Id" />` and  `<div>Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" style="width:50px;" /></div>` is generating invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes). In any case its unclear why you have these since you don't appear to have a form (and if you do, this will never bind to your model when you post anyway)

Comment: Also strongly suggest you use style sheets rather than inline styles (see the fiddle I linked to above.

Comment: I was just using inline styles to get it layed ut right, I plan on putting it all in a stylesheet in the end. The hidden form element is there because in time there will be a button to add the item to the cart

Comment: Assuming you will be using jquery/ajax to add products to the cart, better to just add the ID as a `data-*` attribute to the button element rather than adding a hidden input. You might also want to take a look at [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/) if your building a shopping cart.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how to I add the ID as a data-* attribute to the button element, can you show an example?

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model) { <button class="addtocart" type="button" data-id="@item.Id">Add to Cart</button> }` then in jquery you can access it using `$('.addtocart').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('id'); ... });`